# Catching delete of a stack object?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Are there tools to catches deletion of a stack object, how likely that gcc and Visual Studio debug build will break on that event immediately?

I deal with big, old projects, so that is not a question on how to write code, but how to detect and fix problems.

Comment: You mean in the sense of explicitly calling `delete` on a stack-based object?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the destructor of the class for the stack object in question, or at the end of the method just before the stack object is going to get cleaned up?

Comment: If all objects of the class are always on the stack, you could give it a private, unimplemented `operator delete`.

Comment: Explicit use of `delete` should be extremely rare (a handful in a large code base). Use RAII instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the heap implementations are not tolerate to invalid pointers (i.e. when you `delete` an address which was not returned to you by the heap). Almost for sure standard windows heap, and CRT's heap (implemented by MSVC) cause a debug breakpoint in such a case.

You may also replace the implementation of `new`/`delete` operators and do the checking yourself (in your case you only want to check if the address belongs to the stack memory, which is easy).

Answer (score 2):

It's very unlikely that such a thing would happen if you design the ownerships in advance and use smart pointers to enforce them if necessary. I doubt that they'll do anything but throw on a generic bad deallocation.

Comment: I am mostly interested in how likely it would not throw, to narrow spectre of problems to look for.

Comment: @q______b: It will immediately throw. It probably won't throw and tell you that this is the specific cause of the problem, but it will almost certainly throw.